# SQL Server : create TABLE with the table name as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a scenario where the table that I create is parameterized.

As an example: I need to create table with the name `Customer_1` for customer with the `id = 1`.

For the second customer I need to create a separate table with the name being `Customer_2`.

Basically the `CREATE TABLE` should be parameterized.

One option that I thought was to create a table and then do rename to the table with the given name.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer ... 
Rename Table Customer to Customer_1
```

What is the right approach to do this with T-SQL in SQL Server?

Comment: You would need to look into `Declare @variables`
Though I would wonder why in the world you would want to give each customer their own table

Comment: `I need to create a separate table` ... it sounds like a really bad idea to create a separate table for each customer.  That won't scale at all.

Comment: `dynamic sql` - search for this

Comment: how do you run your sql queries? as a stored proc, from c# code or other?

Comment: I gave the customer as an example. Don't take it literally. The scenario is that the customer has many containers (C1, C2, C3) and the data corresponding to these has to be stored separately in a different table.

Comment: Yes, Sproc is what we use

Comment: As a rule of thumb, creating database objects is a design time task, not a run time task. Re-think your design.

Comment: does those containers (C1, C2, C3) have same or similar structures? if yes, you can think of a predefined parent table contain all those data with some id code for each of C1, C2,... subtables

Comment: "has to be stored separately in a different table" why is that? a table is a logical construct? what difference does it make if it's all in one table with a key to seperate them?

Comment: yes, the structure is same. The reason for going with different table is that we have need to search the contents and when searching in the container C1, i can also get results that might match in C2 if I keep all the data in the same table. Hence trying to isolate by putting in separate tables. But I agree that a table is design time and not run time task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, modify `@Parameter` with your parameter.

```
DECLARE @Parameter NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Parameter = '1'
SET @SQString = 'CREATE TABLE Customer_'+ @Parameter + '( i int )'
EXEC (@SQString)
GO
```

Comment: `Quotename(@Parameter)` will be safer